# Run Program When Disk Full

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, cpu, monitoring

I'd like to receive a pushover notification when a hard drive is running low on space. I can send the pushover notification by running curl and passing various parameters to it.

What I need to know is how to have a program triggered when a certain disk space % limit is reached.

Bonus points if CPU conditions can also trigger a program.

I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: Not really supposed to recommend software applications on Super User, but I can tell you PRTG and Solarwinds are excellent monitor applications. Pending on how you would like to receive the notification, PRTG and Solarwinds can both be modified to send email and SMS notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be worth a shot but [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/download) is not a terrible solution. Plus it's an excellent tool to learn if you are in the professional IT world.

Answer (score 1):

I like ServersAlive for monitoring and notifying : http://www.woodstone.nu/salive/